# Ruby: exception wrongly raised when testing the creation of a directory

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a module named FileSystem in my app, which executes basic filesystem functionality. Here is the relevant code of it.

```
module TxtDB
  module FileSystem

    def self.create_database(db)
      fpdb = db_full_path(db)
      Dir.mkdir(fpdb) unless ((not valid_parameter?(db)) or (not valid_database?(fpdb)))
    end

    private 

    def self.valid_parameter?(db)
      raise TxtDB::NIL_PARAMETER_ERROR unless (not db == nil)
      raise TxtDB::NOT_A_STRING_ERROR unless (db.is_a? String)
      raise TxtDB::EMPTY_PARAMETER_ERROR unless (not db.empty?)
      true
    end

    def self.valid_database?(db)
      raise TxtDB::DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS_ERROR unless (not Dir.exist?(db_full_path(db)))
      true
    end

    def self.db_full_path(db)
      "#{TxtDB::BASE_DIRECTORY}/#{db}"
    end

  end
end
```

And this is my Rspec test for this feature

```
it 'raises a StandardError (Database already exists) if it receives the name of an existing database' do
  base_path = TxtDB::BASE_DIRECTORY
  if (not Dir.exist?(base_path)) then
    Dir.mkdir(base_path)
  end
  db_path = File.join(TxtDB::BASE_DIRECTORY,'testedb')
  if (not Dir.exist?(db_path)) then
    Dir.mkdir(db_path)
  end
  expect {
    TxtDB::FileSystem::create_database('testedb')
  }.to raise_error(StandardError, TxtDB::DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS_ERROR)
end
```

It happens that when I run my tests I got this error

```
expected StandardError with "Database already exists", got #<Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - txtdb/testedb>
```

As I see things, this should not happen, since I'm testing for the existence before calling **Dir.mkdir**. But I'm obviously wrong, since the error occurs. The question is: **Where am I wrong?**

==========

According to the suggestion of Peter Alfvin (see answer below), I change my method to

```
def self.create_database(db)
  fpdb = db_full_path(db)
  if (valid_parameter?(db) and valid_database?(fpdb)) then
    Dir.mkdir(fpdb)
  end
end
```

Now there is no doubt the validations are done beforehand. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dir.exists?(path)` returns `true` if path is a directory, otherwise it returns `false`. In `valid_database?`, you are passing it the full path name, which I would guess is pointing to a non-directory file.

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-exists-3F

Comment: But this is the point: valid_database? raises a StandardError if the database exists. This is checked before the Dir.mkdir, not after. This error should be risen before the error in Dir.mkdir, don't you think?

Comment: But it is there, @peter-alfvin! Haven't you read the post? The code is  there! Read the methods again, please!

Comment: The only point in the method valid_database? is the it tests if there is already a directory with the name passe. If there is, the databade is not valid to be created, because it already exists.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. I've updated my answer and am going to delete my misleading comment.

Comment: It happens. We miss some things sometimes.

Comment: Exactly. Dir.exist?(path) returns true in my test, because I previously created this directory, cause my test is just to check if it raises the correct error when the directory already exists.

Comment: Yes! You were right, @peter-alfvin! I was passin the full path and then testing for it doubled. Like: I pass /a/b and then ask for the existance of /a/b/a/b. I changed it to pass just the name of the directory and the test worked! Thanks a lot!